# Add Rows To Resultset Based On SQL Result

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, resultset

I have a table that contains a bill of process for multiple items. I would like to add rows to the result based on the current sequence number and adding a relevant process name to my new rows, e.g.:

**ItemCode Sequence  Process**

ABC-1 **10** Disperse

ABC-1        **15**     Hold

ABC-1        **20**     Grind

ABC-1        **30**     Mix

Each current result row should create 3 additional rows (1 preceding and 2 after the existing sequence number), e.g.:

**Item  Sequence    Process**

ABC-1        **09** Disperse - Load

ABC-1        **10** Disperse - Process

ABC-1        **11** Disperse - Wait

ABC-1        **12** Disperse - Empty

ABC-1        **14** Hold - Load

ABC-1        **15** Hold - Process

ABC-1        **16** Hold - Wait

ABC-1        **17** Hold - Empty

ABC-1        **19** Grind - Load

ABC-1        **20** Grind - Process

ABC-1        **21** Grind - Wait

ABC-1        **22** Grind - Empty

ABC-1        **29** Mix - Load

ABC-1        **30** Mix - Process

ABC-1        **31** Mix - Wait

ABC-1        **32** Mix - Empty

As shown, I would also like to be able to handle the value of the Process column (where Load is sufficed to the preceding row, process suffixes the existing row, wait suffixes the next row and empty suffixes the row after that).

Is such a thing even possible in an elegant manner? I'm a relative novice. Any cues are greatly appreciated.

M :)

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, though it needs to be done in multiple steps.  I would do it in 4.

First you'll need to an UPDATE that simply adds ' - Process' to your existing `Process` values.

Then I would do 3 INSERTs.  One for each of the related rows you want to add around each row.  For each row that now has ' - Process' in it, INSERT a row with the same `Item` value, a `Sequence` value that is the current one -1/+1/+2 and the current `Process` value, REPLACE() ' - Process' with ' - Load' etc.

EDIT:  I just noticed you are looking to modify a resultset and not make changes to the data in the table.  In that case, you could start by inserting your current resultset into a table variable and then perform the steps I described above to the table variable, and end with a SELECT from the table variable.

If you wanted a single SELECT, you could substitute all of the above steps with a UNION ALL of 4 CTEs, but I doubt it would have much of a performance benefit, and it would make for a more complicated query to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

This is not too bad to produce. Taking your sample data and converting this into a table variable is where we need to start. I changed the name from Sequence to MySequence because it is best not to use reserved words for object or column names.

```
declare @Something table
(
    ItemCode varchar(10)
    , MySequence int
    , Process varchar(10)
)
insert @Something
values
('ABC-1', 10, 'Disperse')
,('ABC-1', 15, 'Hold')
,('ABC-1', 20, 'Grind')
,('ABC-1', 30, 'Mix')
```

Now that we have a table with your data it is pretty easy using a table valued constructor to build a table for your values.

```
select s.ItemCode
    , MySequence = s.MySequence + x.Multiplier
    , Process = s.Process + ' - ' + x.ProcessExtension
from @Something s
cross apply
(
    values
    (-1, 'Load')
    , (0, 'Process')
    , (1, 'Wait')
    , (2, 'Empty')
)x(Multiplier, ProcessExtension)
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it's producing the desired results...

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TestData', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #TestData;

CREATE TABLE #TestData (
    ItemCode CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    Sequense INT NOT NULL,
    Process VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL 
    );
INSERT #TestData (ItemCode, Sequense, Process) VALUES
    ('ABC-1', 10, 'Disperse'),
    ('ABC-1', 15, 'Hold'),
    ('ABC-1', 20, 'Grind'),
    ('ABC-1', 30, 'Mix');

--==================================================

SELECT 
    td.ItemCode, 
    s.Sequense, 
    Process = CONCAT(td.Process, ' - ', s.Process)
FROM
    #TestData td
    CROSS APPLY ( VALUES    
                        (td.Sequense - 1, 'Load'),
                        (td.Sequense, 'Process'),
                        (td.Sequense + 1, 'Wait')
                    ) s (Sequense, Process);
```